# Getters and setters alternative

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have got a MVC structure where Im setting the color of a JPanel in a JPanel-class. I wonder which of the two alternatives is the best solution.

1. Setting the color in the Controller-class by forwarding the method with getters to the Panel-class
2. Setting the color in the Panel-class with setters as in alternative 2.

Alternative 2 sounds as a better solution to me but don’t know if it there is a big difference since both are working so if thats the case, why?

Thanks a lot!

---

**ALTERNATIVE 1:**

**controller class**

In running thread:

```
theView.getPanelClass().getPanel().setBackground(new Color(255));
```

**View class**

```
private final PanelClass panel = new PanelClass();

public PanelClass getPanelClass() {
    return panel;
}
```

**Panel class (declared in theView)**

```
JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

public JPanel getPanel() {
    return thePanel;
}
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE 2:**

**Controller class**
In running thread:

```
theView.setPanel(new Color(255));
```

**View class**

```
private final PanelClass panel = new PanelClass();

public void setPanel(Color col) {
   panel.setThePanel(col);
}
```

**Panel class (declared in theView)**

```
JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

public void setThePanel(Color c) {
    thePanel.setBackground(c);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
I have now edited my code as follows so the view class are setting the color through the JPanel class.

**ALTERNATIVE 3:**

**Controller class**
In running thread:

```
if(x>y) {    
  theView.setPanel(1);
} else {
  theView.setPanel(2);
}
```

**View class**

```
private final PanelClass panel = new PanelClass();

public void setPanel(int n) {
   panel.setThePanel(n);
}
```

**Panel class (declared in theView)**

```
public void setThePanel(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            panelS1.setBackground(new Color(255));
            break;
        case 2:
            panelS1.setBackground(new Color(0));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a contractual decision. If you agree that this is the developer's responsibility to know the internals of your view, and that it is acceptable that he knows about `getPanelClass()` and `getPanel()` prior to setting the background color, then this solution (1) is viable.

If you believe it is abusive to expect programmers to know the implementation details then you'd better go with (2).

Now, there's probably a reason to it, but why are you setting the color from the controller? Shouldn't it be a decision purely made by the view itself anyway? The whole purpose of separating the view from the controller is precisely to not interfere in this kind of decisions. What if you decide to update the view in x years with another component, are you certain it will have a background color setter as well? If so, make sure your current view implements an "ViewWithBackgroundColorSetter" interface for example.

You see I'm expanding a bit but your issue delves deeper than you may think.

Comment: yes but did you consider the responsibility of who or what should actually be doing it? It's most likely that the view should *observe* the x/y comparison and update itself based on it. All that the controller should do is provide the information, not the view update itself.

Comment: Thanks. The reason for why Im setting the color from the controller is that I have different colors according to an if statement.  if(x < y) { setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));} else if (x > y) { theView.getPanelClass().getPanelS2().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0)); }

Comment: I suppose my comment still stands. But it might expand beyond this question as it seems there's a wider architectural issue. I encourage you to consider a code review.

Comment: thanks you got a point. Sorry Im new to the forum. Do you mean to post the same question here as well? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I actually meant it a general way. I'm not sure of their posting policies, it might be a good idea :-) I'm very glad you took it positively! This is the way to go in this field. Good luck and happy coding

Comment: Now I have changed my code according to your recommendations :) So the JPanel class is setting the color. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First alternative seems to violate so called Hollywood principle. I'd rather choose second alternative

Comment: Could you say in general that forwarding one method called from one place  to a different method is in general not a good idea? Such as theVIew.method2().method3();

Comment: It's should be avoided, but as every principle it should also be taken with a grain of salt. Meaning you're not to force it just for the sake of obeying the principle.